# how do I subtract date oracle with one record

Tags: sql, oracle, time

I have a table with one column in the date format. I want to calculate the time difference between two records, can you help me? I need a query in SQL or PL/SQL.

```
ORDER_ID;ORDER_STATUS_ID;ORDER_DATE
8296;16;22-2-2011 13:56:31
8295;22;22-2-2011 13:07:15
```

The query should result in 00:49:45 or close to this.

Can you help? Thx!

BR

Comment: How do you know that these two ORDER_ID's are supposed to be subtracted?  What's the rule the "joins" these two records together?

Comment: Something to think about, for sure.  But the fact that the ORDER_IDs are in sequence implies the user may just be looking for the "idle" time between orders.

Comment: @D.N. What about duplicate or missing ORDER_ID's?

Comment: True, but hopefully it's a unique PK column :)

Answer (score 2):

The question isn't really how you want to calculate it - it is how you want it shown. date arithmetic is simple:

```
select date2 - date1 from
    (select to_Date('22-2-2011 13:07:15','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as date1,
            to_Date('22-2-2011 13:56:31','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as date2
     from dual);
```

gives you the answer, but it is a decimal. So how to translate that into your visual display?

```
select to_char(trunc(sysdate) + mod(date2 - date1,1),'hh24:mi:ss') from
    (select to_Date('22-2-2011 13:07:15','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as date1,
            to_Date('22-2-2011 13:56:31','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as date2
     from dual);
```

OK, now this is nicely formatted.

Oh, except what if you actually want to store the interval? Or if the interval is more than one day then you need to format it differently.

So - is it that you need the actual interval for other purposes? Or that you just want to display the interval in a given format? Depending on what you need will guide your answer.

But the interval itself is easy. That is just subtraction. In your case

```
select yt2.order_Date - yt1.order_date
from yourtable yt1, yourtable yt2
where yt1.order_id = 8295
and   yt2.order_id = 8296;
```

Answer (score 2):

You might find an analytic function helpful.

```
SELECT order_id,
       order_date,
       order_date - LAG(order_date) OVER (ORDER BY order_id) time_since_last_order
  FROM order_table
  WHERE order_id IN (8295,8296) -- or whatever set of orders you're really interested in
  ORDER BY order_id;
```

This avoids the self-join you would otherwise need to connect the two rows.

Aside from that, Michael's answer covers it well.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this site](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_date_time.html).  Depending on if you are using a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` field, the query you need to write will be different.

If this is an important feature, and you want to reduce the difficulty of creating the queries, you may consider switching to `TIMESTAMP` fields, if possible.